# CSS: Positioning divs

Tags: css, positioning, html

how can I get my divs to layout out like the below pic.

```
--------------  -------------------
|            |  |      Div2       |
|            |  -------------------
|   Div1     |  -------------------
|            |  |      Div3       |
|            |  -------------------
|            |  -------------------
|            |  |      Div4       |
--------------  -------------------
```

Everything I've tried has div's 2,3,4 lining up horizontally to each other.  I tried to do clear: left; (or both) but they just end up under div 1.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: It would be helpful to know what your CSS and HTML look like right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work, basicaly the approach is to simply position the elements where you need them, IMO this is an easy way to understand the base layout of your page.  [here](http://jsbin.com/izosi3) you can see an example http://jsbin.com/izosi3/edit

```
<div id="leftnav" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; width:150px;">
</div>
<div id="header" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:150px; height:50px; right:0px;">
</div>
<div id="content" style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:150px; bottom:50px; right:0px;">
</div>
<div id="footer" style="position:absolute; height:50px; left:150px; bottom:0px; right:0px;">
</div>
```

Comment: @fwaokda.. I actually have re-read your question and some of the answers and I'm coming to the conculusion that you do not need the layout to cover the entire page but just a section.  But since your question doesn't specify I will leave my answer until you have a chance to look.

Comment: Your right I did forget to specify.  I was trying to do my layout without specifying widths.  I don't know if it's possible or not. My Div 1 is actually a div with an img... but the img being hosted doesn't have a set size. All the divs to the right are all words so those I figured might have a width but wouldn't be necessary.  I'll look over you answer thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd most likely have a container div for the right side, with the three rows nested within it.

Comment: It is absoutely not necessary to nest the 3 rows on the right side.  CSS can handle that for you.

Answer (score 1):

One of many possible solutions:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
        border: 1px dashed #000;
        width: 300px;
      }
      #div1 {
        float: left;
      }
      #div2, #div3, #div4 {
        margin-left : 300px;
      }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
     <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
     <div id="div3">Div 3</div>
     <div id="div4">Div 4</div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

The `border` is there just to aid in seeing the divs.

Answer (score 0):

How is that

**Html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="big">biggy</div>
    <div class="small">1</div>
    <div class="small">2</div>
    <div class="small">3</div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.container{
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.big{
    width:160px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#c55;
    padding:5px;
}
.small{
    width:180px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#5c5;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

**demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/em7yz/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.  But you'll have to explicitly set the height of your DIV's.

```
<div style="width:600px;height:600px;border:1px solid red;">
   <div style="float:left;width:300px;height:600px;border:1px solid green;">
      <h1>Div 1</h1>
   </div>
   <div style="float:left;">
      <div style="height:200px;width:298px;border:1px solid orange;"><h1>Div 2</h1></div>
      <div style="height:200px;width:298px;border:1px solid blue;"><h1>Div 3</h1></div>
      <div style="height:200px;width:298px;border:1px solid purple;"><h1>Div 4</h1></div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```